# Facebook object not found

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Via the Facebook Graph API it is possible to get the cover image of an event via the following GET-Request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/169768270447838?fields=cover&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKES>
```

Good for the following event id it works (UrL: https://www.facebook.com/events/925315510978238/):

> 925315510978238

But for the other event id it doesnt work anymore (https://www.facebook.com/events/169768270447838/):

> 169768270447838

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '169768270447838' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "CnDEBaBv1HG"
}
```

}

It worked few days ago, and I dont know why it doesnt work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely related to this:

> Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process should resume in a few weeks, but apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

This may be interesting for you too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

Comment: Thank you, overlooked this one